# JPA -- named-query vs query

Tags: sql, jpa

One way of conducting an SQL query is the defined *NamedQuery* in JPA:

```
Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("Users.findByName");
```

An alternative to this is running it without defining a *NamedQuery*:

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT SELECT u FROM Users u");
```

From what i see, *NamedQuery* is favorable for  it is defined at one-place-for-all in the entity class and is available to a pojo that has a use for it without getting into SQL.

Are there any differences between the two?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only difference is that one is a String that only can be used in the class where is declared, the one of your second example

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery(" SELECT u FROM Users u");
```

The NamedQueries can be used in different DAO without need to define them again, just call and PersistenceProvider will find them using `@NamedQueries - @NamedQuery`, or xml files when you define them.

> Basically a named queries are a powerful tool for organizing query
>   definition and improving application performance.

Also a good important stuff is that some provider processed the JPQL inside the namedqueries  at the startup time, this gives a hit on the performance, in the second case that you set in yout question, persistence provider is not aware of the query existence and does not have the chance to process it on startup and need to run the process when is required.

Comment: your last paragraph can well be an advantage for the second case -- when a specific query is needed only in that pojo (if it comes to that at runtime) and thus doesn't slow down the startup by parsing it all among the namedQueries.

Comment: Yes that could happens unless it are a dynamic query, with that provider can do nothing, also I'm not sure how 'if it comes to that at runtime' this could happen if the query is not marked with NamedQuery, as I know provider does not scan String that can be queries in the POJO´s at startup time